# potential leak value stored never read in NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsmutablearray

NOTE: i want to alloc my NSMutableArray and then assign data in it.

i got leak in below code

```
NSMutableArray *responseArr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
                responseArr =[response valueForKey:@"result"];
```

Also in here value stored never read

```
 NSString *name=_txt_name.text;
    if ([name length]==0) {
        name=@"";
    }
```

Also leak in below

```
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"];

    //below here i get leak 
    NSDate *dateStart = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    dateStart = [dateFormatter dateFromString:startDate];
```

**EDIT** :
I have disable ARC using -fno-objc-arc in reachability Class even i get below leaks

[image]

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: sorry got leak not error

Comment: There is no reason for any of the code shown to cause leaks.  You will get warnings if you create variables and then never read from them; the compiler is warning you that you are performing unnecessary operations

Comment: Can tell us if u use ARC or not?

Comment: i have not use ARC

Comment: Why aren't you using ARC?  Use ARC!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line

```
NSMutableArray *responseArr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

Allocates a new NSMutableArray and assigns a reference to it to `responseArr`

This line

```
responseArr = [response valueForKey:@"result"];
```

Takes a value from a dictionary (that presumably is a reference to an NSMutableArray) and assigns that to `responseArr`.  At this point there are no more references to the original `NSMutableArray` that you allocated, so it will be deallocated.

You can just say:

```
 NSMutableArray *responseArr = (NSMutableArray *)response[@"result"];
```

Similarly with your date code, you could just say:

```
NSDate *dateStart = [dateFormatter dateFromString:startDate];
```

There is no need to assign an initial value, only to throw it away.

None of the code you have shown will cause leaks, assuming you are using ARC.

If you aren't using ARC, then start using ARC!

Comment: He does not use ARC.

Comment: hello @paulw  
is 
 NSMutableDictionary *Data=[NSMutableDictionary new]; 
 Data =(NSMutableDictionary*)[arrData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Is equivalent =>
    NSMutableDictionary * Data = (NSMutableDictionary *)[arrData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Comment: Kind of.  In the first case you are unnecessary allocating and then discarding a dictionary.  In the second case you aren't, but in both cases `Data` will have the same value

Comment: means whenever new value is in arrData it will assign to Data dictionary right ? thanks for clearance

Comment: No.  It doesn't mean that.  It means that `Data` will refer to the dictionary that was stored in `arrData[indexPath.row]`.  If a different dictionary is stored in that index of the array then `Data` will still refer to the original dictionary, but until that point `arrData[indexPath.row]` and `Data` will refer to the same dictionary

Comment: yes...i alloc the NSMutableDictionary so its last value should be clear and then new value assign in it. so NSMutableDictionary * Data = (NSMutableDictionary *)[arrData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; it will work in it ??

And last question then i will accept your answer , what about if we have to fix an NSMutableArray with capacity ? NSMutableArray *arr_Cap = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:4];

Comment: What about array capacity?  All that initialiser does is provide a hint as to how many items will be in the array; typically you use this if you know that there will be a large number of elements to prevent the overhead of allocating more memory for the array later.  4 is a very small array, so I wouldn't expect it to make any difference compared to `[NSMutableArray new]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138182/discussion-between-iphonemaclover-and-paulw11).

Answer (score 1):

A. First snippet

Using MRC (MRR) you have to balance allocations with `+alloc` your own:

```
NSMutableArray *responseArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
                responseArr = [response valueForKey:@"result"];
```

In the first line you allocate an instance of `NSArray`. You have to (auto-)release it later, otherwise it is a memory leak. I think you misunderstood that you create a *new* instance of `NSArray` using `-valueForKey` and assign the value of this new reference to `responseArr`. (Therefore you do not need a mutable array.) After that you created *two* objects having only one reference to the new one, you can never release the old one.

Do something like this:

```
NSArray *responseArr = [[NSArray alloc]init];
NSArray *resultArr =[response valueForKey:@"result"];
[responseArr release];
```

You do not have to do that with the object referred by `resultArr`, because it isn't created with `+alloc-init`. [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MemoryManagement.html) you get an introduction to ownership.

B. Third snippet

It is the same with the last example:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
```

You +alloc-init that instance object, but there is no release in your code. Therefore it cannot be released anymore, when the reference `dateFormatter` loses its extent (lifetime), i. e. returning from the method.

Add this code at the end of the method:

```
[dateFormatter release];
```

C. Second snippet

The second example has a different problem: You assign a value to the var `name` without using the variable in the code below. So assigning the value is meaningless.